# R: Cannot read shiny objects Error: Reading objects from shiny output object not allowed

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

```r
genres <- c("Pop", "Rap")
bins <- c(0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("Greens", domain = c(0,2000), bins = bins)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Concert Ticket Prices Spotify & Seat Geek"),
  dashboardSidebar(selectInput("genre", label = "Genre",choices = genres, selected = "Rap")),

  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(box(width = 12,leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap"))),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data Set (CSV)'),
    fluidRow(box(width = 12, dataTableOutput(outputId = "summary_table"))),
    fluidRow(textOutput(outputId = "n1")),
  )



)
server <- function(input, output, session){



  text <- reactive({input$genre})
  text2 <- reactive({text()})



  genre_shp <- Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == text2,]








  labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>Average Price: $%g <br/>%s </br> %s, %s <br/> %s ",
  genre_shp$Artist, genre_shp$`Avg Price`, genre_shp$Venue, genre_shp$City, genre_shp$name, genre_shp$`Data & Time`
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)



  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet(
    leaflet(genre_shp) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 4) %>%
  addProviderTiles("MapBox", options = providerTileOptions(
    id = "mapbox.light",
    accessToken = Sys.getenv('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'))) %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(genre_shp$`Avg Price`),
    weight = 2,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white",
    dashArray = "3",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    highlight = highlightOptions(
      weight = 5,
      color = "#666",
      dashArray = "",
      fillOpacity = 0.7,
      bringToFront = TRUE),
    label = labels,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
      textsize = "15px",
      direction = "auto")) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, 
            values = genre_shp$`Avg Price`, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
    position = "bottomright")

    )
  genres <- c("Pop", "Rap")
bins <- c(0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("Greens", domain = c(0,2000), bins = bins)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "green",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Concert Ticket Prices Spotify & Seat Geek"),
  dashboardSidebar(selectInput("genre", label = "Genre",choices = genres, selected = "Rap")),

  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(box(width = 12,leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap"))),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data Set (CSV)'),
    fluidRow(box(width = 12, dataTableOutput(outputId = "summary_table"))),
    fluidRow(textOutput(outputId = "n1")),
  )



)
server <- function(input, output, session){



  text <- reactive({input$genre})
  text2 <- reactive({text()})



  genre_shp <- Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == text2,]








  labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>Average Price: $%g <br/>%s </br> %s, %s <br/> %s ",
  genre_shp$Artist, genre_shp$`Avg Price`, genre_shp$Venue, genre_shp$City, genre_shp$name, genre_shp$`Data & Time`
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)



  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet(
    leaflet(genre_shp) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 4) %>%
  addProviderTiles("MapBox", options = providerTileOptions(
    id = "mapbox.light",
    accessToken = Sys.getenv('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'))) %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(genre_shp$`Avg Price`),
    weight = 2,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white",
    dashArray = "3",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    highlight = highlightOptions(
      weight = 5,
      color = "#666",
      dashArray = "",
      fillOpacity = 0.7,
      bringToFront = TRUE),
    label = labels,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
      textsize = "15px",
      direction = "auto")) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, 
            values = genre_shp$`Avg Price`, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
    position = "bottomright")

    )

   output$summary_table <- renderDataTable(data.frame(genre_shp))



   output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste('SelectedRows', '.csv', sep='')
      },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(genre_shp, file)
    }
    )




}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

I am trying to build a dashboard that updates using a drop down menu. The data I have is concerts that will be performed and their costs. I have a large data set that needs to be split for the plotting, as I plan to plot by genre using a map of the US. However when I try to get the data from input$genre I am not allowed to leverage the output to filter my data frame for plotting. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you 
All the best
M

Answer (score 0):

This part looks weird to me

```r
text <- reactive({input$genre})
text2 <- reactive({text()})

genre_shp <- Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == text2,]
```

Why not simply

```r
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet( {
genre_shp <- Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == input$genre,]
leaflet(genre_shp)
})
```

Comment: Still no luck,  I tried:  genre_shp <- renderLeaflet({Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == input$genre,]}) and  renderLeaflet({genre_shp <- Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == input$genre,]}), Now i get an error saying closure is not subsettable and the app wont run

Comment: It is at this point that you mention where the app fails - all else should run its just this last part to connect the data to the leaflet plot

Comment: I have updated the answer a bit - could you try just running this simple version to see if you can get `mymap` to render properly on the `ui` side?

Comment: the same problem occurs as with the fix SmokeyShakers suggested. When i run the serve the genre_shp does successfully update the data for the summary output, but it doesnt work for the plot. I get know return when i set the labels to genre_shp$variable and i get a return when i convert them back but use genre_shp for everything other than labels, howver that return does not contain a leaflet output. Where it should be I get ->  Error: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Answer (score 0):

This is a no go:

```
  text <- reactive({input$genre})
  text2 <- reactive({text()})

  genre_shp <- Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == text2,]
```

The first two lines are not necessary.  The third is not possible since `text2` is a reactive value.
Just do:

```
genre_shp <- reactive(Allgenre[Allgenre$genre == input$genre,])
```

Then use `genre_shp()` as your leaflet argument.

Comment: A little bit of good news here. This does allow for the data set to be read in and expressed through the output summary, but my leaflet plot is still not appearing

Comment: I still get: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: It seems to not like how my labels are set up when i do something like genre_shp()$`Avg Price` nothing renders. When I keep everything but change the labels to instead be orgData$`Avg Price`, a portion of the data I have for testing, than the app runs and but drop down works for my summary of stat, but not my leaflet

Comment: Ah, So you can't do `genre_shp()` unless you're in a reactive context.

Comment: In the shiny app i get this error in place of my leafletplot: Error: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Comment: It seems to be the case, any advice on how to address those labels? sorry for throwing so much at you btw, but i appreciate the insight

Comment: So,  fundamental in Shiny is that objects that are reactive, like `genre_shp()` and `input$genre` can only be used in reactive contexts.   Any object affected by these, must also be reactive, like your labels

Comment: Like `labels <- reactive({sprintf(...`

Comment: Honestly, I think you're best bet is to review [reactivity basics](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).   You're headed in the right direction, but need a little background on what you can and can't do in Shiny. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for everything. I have been reviewing the basics but at times it gets frustrating. So ive made the labels reactive so now the app renders, but i received a new error Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list' -> so something doesn't like that ive referenced a function